# How to mark a place using google map

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set a contact page in which I display google's map to indicate the place of a meet. I'm currently using using these codes:

js

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display="block";
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0)
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
})();
```

html

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/js/google-map.js">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height: 400px; margin:auto;"></div>
```

The problem is that I couldn't be able to mark the indicated place like in google map to precise to the user the indicated place. Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: see google documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define the Latitude and Longitude of the mark

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
```

Then you need to add a marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

Take a look at
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es